# Show php print_r in Flash?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

Trying to figure out a way to get ActionScript to print out a php object.  In PHP, I can just do print_r, and I'm able to successfully get the object into Flash, but now can't figure out how to print out the object using ActionScript 3?

Comment: Define "get the object into Flash"

Answer (score 0):

Well, when the request first comes over, there is always URLLoader.data, which is data in its raw form. If you're looking to get the data from a JSON-style object, there is `for( var i:String in obj )`. If you're looking for things more obscure than that, there is the ability to use describeType. My favorite example of the last one is in the [JSONEncoder](http://as3corelib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/com/adobe/serialization/json/JSONEncoder.as) class.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP, you can encode most objects to JSON using `json_encode()` (PHP5+).  Using the AS3 JSON decoder from [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) you can then convert that encoded string into an oject that AS3 con read. After that you can iterate over the object as key/value pairs and output it however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean, I had the same need, so I made this

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=266979

scroll to the bottom, there is a description and an .AS file called trace_r that I wrote

Comment: "Go to some other site" is not an answer.  The important parts should be here.